# Android : How to parse a string with a multicharacter delimitation

Tags: android, parsing

I want to parse this string " hello>kok>peoplekok"
I want the delimiter to be not just a character but a string. Let's say ">kok>" so the result will be 1 : hello      2: peoplekok

I've look into split() method but it seems that the delimitation are only caracters.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the split method takes regular expressions :) Try

```
"hello>kok>peoplekok".split(">kok>");
```

and also have a look at this [LINK](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: Ok, it works !! thanks. I did try these at first but as my string was very big, the logger splitted the very long line by himself just for display and i thought it didn't work :(.

Answer (score 1):

```
String testString = "hello>kok>peoplekok";
String result[] = testString.split("">kok>");
```

now the result contains the answer

```
result[0] =  hello
result[1] =  peoplekok
```